# Don't know where the Request object is comng from

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, httprequest

So there is this method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Summary(string id, Summary model)
{
  int projectID;
  if (Int32.TryParse(id, out projectID))
  {
   switch (Request["PageType"])
   {
      case "Results":
       model = new Summary(SummaryType.SCS, GetSCSData(projectID, Request["Names"], true), projectID, SCSView.ResultsPage);
       break;
      case "Recipients":
       model = new Summary(SummaryType.SCS, GetProjectData(projectID, Request["Names"]), projectID)
       {
          Names = Request["Names"],
          HTMLAttachment = ParseBool(Request["HTMLAttachment"])
        };
        break;                    
       default:
        model = new Summary();
         break;
        }
    }
```

And was wondering where the `Request["Names"]` came from. I understand that is the request object from my Http request call. But how was it constructed and sent? I know it has something to do with my view, which look like this

```
 using (Html.BeginForm(Summary, "Mycontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "gridForm" }))
  { 
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.scsGridList) ... kendo stuff
    <input id="gridPage" name="PageType" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input id="gridProjectID" name="ProjectID" type="hidden" value="@Model.ProjectID" />
    <input id="gridJobs" name="Jobs" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input id="gridHTMLAttach" name="HTMLAttachment" type="hidden" value="true" />
  <div style="width: 100%; padding-top:5px;">                           
    <a id="email" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed linkicon"></span>Email</a>                            
  </div>
```

In my javascript is this

```
$("#email").on("click", function (e) {
        SendTo("Recipients");
    });

function SendTo(pageType){
    var values = GetSelectedValues();
    if(values){
        $("#gridPage").val(pageType);
        $("#gridJobs").val(values);
        $("#gridForm").submit();
    } else {
        $("#gridMessage").html("Please select a job.");
    }
}
```

I am just confuse as to how the Request object came to be populated with data such as `Request["HTMLAttachment"]` and `Request["Names"]`. Does it know to map to the model? Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you placed all your inputs inside form, then when you submit it browser will populate key-value pairs, where keys are the names of inpurs inside form. It will do for every input element in form, even invisible. 
And as it stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948(v=vs.90).aspx

> The Request object retrieves the values that the client browser passed
>   to the server during an HTTP request.

This is provided to you by asp.net for free. asp.net mvc uses it. http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request

Comment: I am curious as to where Id and Model came from then?

Comment: This called Model Binding. Read more here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405(v=vs.100).aspx